# Who are all the characters from the UK book covers of The Witcher series?

Tags: character-identification, the-witcher, cover-art

I recently acquired these paperback books from *The Witcher* series, and they are decorated with characters on the facing cover page, and I really enjoy them and wish to know who all these characters are, I recognize some of them but I would like to know for sure who they are.

[image: The UK cover books laid out with numbers on top to identify them]

From what I can collect so far I think it's these characters but I would like some confirmation:

1. Milva.
2. Yennefer (I am not sure about this one but it seems the most logical to me)
3. ?
4. Ciri
5. Cahir
6. Dandelion.
7. Geralt.
8. Regis (I am also quite unsure about this one but it feels close by).

If anyone could clear this up that would be ace!

Comment: [Someone has an answer here](https://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/8kezec/who_are_the_characters_in_the_uk_covers_for_bof/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf), not sure if it’s correct or not though.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Yes I believe it is correct.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's all the protagonists (Geralt, Ciri, Yennefer, Dandelion) and other prominent characters from Geralt's party in the series. Plus Lytta Neyd on the cover of the stand-alone book Season of Storms.

Without having any trustworthy source for it and just going by their looks and book motifs, then:

**1. "Milva" - Maria Barring**

Defining attributes: the only archer among the prominent characters, forest motif.

**2. Yennefer of Vengerberg**

Defining attributes: the only character with violet eyes. Dark hair.

**3. "Coral" - Lytta Neyd**

Defining attributes: the only prominent female character from the stand-alone book *Season of Storms*. Red hair. Sea motif.

**4. "Ciri" - Cirilla Fiona Elen Riannon**

Defining attributes: ashen hair, teenager, she is the one referred to as "The Lady of the Lake".

**5. Cahir Mawr Dyffryn aep Ceallach**

Defining attributes: helmet with wings, armor, dark hair. Better picture [here](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Cahir_Mawr_Dyffryn_aep_Ceallach).

**6. "Dandelion" - Julian Alfred Pankratz**

Defining attributes: holding a lute, impractical fancy clothing.

**7.  Geralt of Rivia**

Defining attributes: white hair, orange eyes.

**8. "Regis" - Emiel Regis Rohellec Terzieff-Godefroy**

Defining attributes: grey hair, alchemy/botanical motif. Long nails is a likely hint of a vampire.